# Set a global service for import in Create React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, import, create-react-app

Is it possible to somehow declare a jsx file as a global file or a directory for import? For example instead of:

```
import { Navigation } from '../../../../../../helpers/NavigationService';
```

do just:

```
import { Navigation } from 'NavigationService';
```

I've seen it's possible in webpack config, but I don't see this file in create-react-app. Can I use somehow package.json for that?

Comment: afaik this is currently not possible without ejecting the project. There was a propose to make that configurable in `package.json` but it was not yet accepted and it is not clear if it ever will.

Comment: Another possible approach is to extract your "helpers" to a separate package, and install it with npm/yarn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three ways to solve your issue:

1. NODE_PATH (<- probably what you're looking for):

You can define an environment variable NODE_PATH=src/ and then you can import your service like so `import { Navigation } from 'helpers/NavigationService';`. It'll will work but this is not necessary what's best in my opinion.

2. No deep nesting:
   No nesting, means no issue of deep nesting in the first place. You can try having a file hierarchy similar to this:

```
src/
  /helpers
  /components/
    /componentA/
      componentA
      relatedComponent
      otherRelatedComponent <- no need for nesting
    /componentB/
  ...
```

3. The mono repo approach:

Having an internal helper package and have it imported like `import { Navigation } from 'myproject-helpers/NavigationService';` may be a good compromise

Comment: Can I build such packages inside my create-react-app project? Like define packages that should be built and added like node_modules as imports like moment, redux?

Comment: @mikes Yes here is an example using lerna (+ yarn workspace, although not necessary) https://github.com/fazouane-marouane/cra-yarn-workspace/tree/patch-1/packages I'll probably make another version of it and keep it to a bare minimum sometimes in the futur, but it's a good start.

Answer (score 1):

You could set `NODE_PATH='src'` in `.env` file, using global imports instead, here's my solution, without having to eject.

`.env`:

```
NODE_PATH='src'
```

Create a folder `src/services`, inside it create the `NavigationService`, my example:

```
// src/services/NavigationService.js

export class NavigationService {
  static runIt() {
    console.log("Running");
  }
}
```

In the `App.js` file, now you can import the navigation service directly, using global import, as follows:

```
// src/App.js

// ... import React and others

import { NavigationService } from "services/NavigationService";

class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    NavigationService.runIt();
  }

   // ... render method
}
```

If using VsCode, to get code completion, create `jsconfig.json` file, with the following:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "services/*": ["./src/services/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

I hope it helps!